# dmesg "kernel: [3179429.878254] loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 325360"?

Tags: kernel, dmesg

Ubuntu 22.04

I find in dmesg this:

```
kernel: [3179429.878254] loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 325360
```

Yesterday was a similar message but for loop2. What does this indicate? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The message is printed from the function `set_capacity_and_notify` in the file `block/genhd.c` (gendisk handling), in the kernel source tree. In your context the call comes from the file `drivers/block/loop.c`. See [man loop](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man4/loop.4.html) for more details about loop devices, but the first part is copied and pasted here:

> The  loop  device  is  a  block device that maps its data blocks not
> to a physical device such as a hard disk or optical disk drive, but to
> the blocks of a regular file in a filesystem or to another block
> device.  This can be useful for example to provide a block device for
> a filesystem image stored in a file, so that it can be mounted with
> the mount(8) command.

There are multiple calls to `loop_set_size`, which calls `set_capacity_and_notify`, within `drivers/block/loop.c` so we would need more details as to what you are doing to isolate further.

Try the `losetup` command to learn more about potential `/dev/loop#` devices: Example:

```
doug@desk-jj:~$ /sbin/losetup --list
NAME        SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                                        DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop1          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_16202.snap               0     512
/dev/loop8          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_137.snap      0     512
/dev/loop6          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3252.snap             0     512
/dev/loop13         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1534.snap   0     512
/dev/loop4          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_2015.snap              0     512
/dev/loop11         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_959.snap           0     512
/dev/loop2          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1852.snap              0     512
/dev/loop0          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap                   0     512
/dev/loop9          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_141.snap        0     512
/dev/loop7          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3290.snap             0     512
/dev/loop14         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_143.snap      0     512
/dev/loop5          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_864.snap               0     512
/dev/loop12         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_638.snap           0     512
/dev/loop3          0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_14946.snap               0     512
/dev/loop10         0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap   0     512
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not doing anything: this PC is running headless and what it does for a living is process audio 24/7 for broadcast by our community radio station. It's uptime now is 35 days and I'm not doing anything with it other than watching the desktop via VNC and following dmesg via SSH. Yesterday's loop2 and today's loop5 kernel messages are the first time this type of message has come up. Is there a way I can dig more deeply into this to see what's up?

Comment: try the `df` command. If a loop device is mounted, it should list a bit more information about it. (There might be a better way, I don't know.)

Comment: Thank you. /sbin/losetup --list shows a whole lot of loop devices, about 15, and they are all /var/lib/snapd/snaps entries.; today's loop5 is "chromium_2713.snap", yesterday's loop2 is "core22_1033.snap." df shows no loop mounts. So maybe this is snapd getting its head up its rear end?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a confirmed answer to my question but I think these loop capacity change notifications are just part of something snapd is doing. Here is a bit of today's dmesg output:

```
Dec 10 11:48:48 AirchainProcessor snapd[825]: storehelpers.go:773: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "chromium", "core20", "core22", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gnome-42-2204", "gtk-common-themes", "snapd"
Dec 10 16:23:48 AirchainProcessor snapd[825]: storehelpers.go:773: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "chromium", "core22", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gnome-42-2204", "gtk-common-themes", "snapd"
Dec 10 16:23:53 AirchainProcessor kernel: [3407112.772338] loop1: detected capacity change from 0 to 130888
Dec 10 16:23:54 AirchainProcessor snapd[825]: storehelpers.go:773: cannot refresh snap "core20": snap has no updates available
Dec 10 20:43:48 AirchainProcessor snapd[825]: storehelpers.go:773: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "chromium", "core20", "core22", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gnome-42-2204", "gtk-common-themes", "snapd"
```

So maybe nothing to see here.